# Visual Studio integration with Unity is not working

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, autocomplete

I have installed Visual Studio and Unity separately, but I've installed the "Game Development With Unity" module in VS and I've done the usual fix that people suggest of going into Unity's "Edit > Preferences > External Tools" and setting the External Code Editor to Visual Studio while VS is closed and then reopening it by clicking a script, still doesn't work.

Comment: on windows or Mac?

Comment: i'm on windows 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these possible solutions:

1. Do not open Visual studio manually. Open the script directly from Unity.
2. Make sure that you've installed *Visual Studio Editor* package from the Unity Package Manager window
3. Restarting your computer might do the trick.
4. Update Visual Studio.
5. If the layout of files & solution does not seem correct in Visual Studio, open the Unity Project Explorer window instead of solution explorer.

Comment: I've done all of these things but still doesn't work, could this be because i installed unity and vs separately and not toghether?

Comment: No. Separate installation should not be a problem. However, if none of these solve the problem & you found no else possible solution, doing that might solve the problem.